# How can I make it so my data doesn't get cut off when reading a file using the read function

Tags: c

```
main ()
{
    char *temp_list[4096];
    char *list[4096];
    char *token,*token2 = NULL;
    char *ptr;
    int countries;
    ssize_t rd_countries;
    char temp_buf[512];
    char buf[512];
    size_t nbytes;
    char *file_name = "AllCountries.dat";
    int temp = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    int i, j = 0;
```

Here I open the file then later read it.

```
    countries = open(file_name,O_RDONLY);
    nbytes = sizeof(buf);
```

I then do a do-while loop to read and tokenize the data by commas but the 512 byte buffer size clips off data and adds more than needed.

```
    do {
        rd_countries = read(countries, buf, nbytes - 1);
        if (rd_countries>-1) {
            buf[rd_countries] = '\0';
        }

        token = strtok_r(buf, ",", &ptr);
        while (token != NULL) {
            temp_list[i] = strdup(token);
            printf("%s\n  |||||||||||  ", temp_list[i]);
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &ptr);
            i = i + 1;
        }
    printf("-----------");
    } while (rd_countries != 0);
```

Here's some of the output. As you can see, Eastern Africa turns into Eastern A and frica instead of the correct output because the buffer clips it.

```
The temp list: IOT
The temp list: British Indian Ocean Territory
The temp list: Africa
The temp list: Eastern A
The temp list: frica
The temp list: 78
The temp list: NULL
The temp list: 0
The temp list: NULL
The temp list: 0
The temp list: British Indian Ocean Territory
The temp list: Dependent Territory of the UK
The temp list: Elisabeth II
The temp list: NULL
The temp list: IO
```

Comment: You'll get clipping every 512 bytes because of the size of `buf`. I don't see any reason why you would get clipped where you did.

Comment: (the file is must larger i just showed the part where it clips) yea i know but thats the requirement i just want to know how to move the file pointer back to the last known "\n" but i cant figure it out

Comment: You should get the size of the file with `fstat()`, then allocate a buffer big enough for the whole file and read into it.

Comment: Never ever paste tabs into the editor window here, it'll mess up your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the entire file at once, instead of in 512-byte chunks. You can get the file size with `fstat()`.

```
struct stat statbuf;
fstat(countries, &statbuf);
buf = malloc(statbuf.st_size+1);
rd_countries = read(countries, buf, statbuf.st_size);
buf[rd_countries] = '\0';
```

Comment: i have to use 512 bytes for the buffer

Comment: If you have to use a fixed size buffer, you can't use `strtok()`, because there's no way to know whether it stopped because it reached the end of the buffer or because of a `,` in the buffer.

Comment: This is a crazy restriction.

Comment: i don't know thats just the requirements and i cant figure it out

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Maybe the lesson related to the assignment gives some hint about how you're supposed to solve it?

Comment: Is the file a single line, or is it in lines that are less than 512 bytes? Maybe you're supposed to read it line by line, not fill the whole buffer?

Comment: the file is multiple lines probably 500 and supposed to fill the buffer then move the file pointer back so that it doesn't cut off the word but i don't know how

Comment: After reading the buffer, you could use `strrchr()` to find the last `,` in the buffer. Save everything after it in another variable, then process the tokens. Then when you read the next buffer, concatenate its first token to this variable.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. There's no file pointer anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have restriction of 512 bytes then do following.

- You need to take a variable byte2read inside loop which will see how 
  many bytes are still left in 512 bytes buffer.
- put a condition check after while loop and see if byte2read > 0.
- if yes then while reading file again read only 512 - byte2read and pass buf+byte2read as start of your buffer.

Comment: well the buffer will be full as there is probably 10000 bytes in the file so it wouldn't have less than 512 bytes to read until EOF is reached right?